# show adds(google admob) in iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, admob

In Google site there are 3-4 types of add banners, banner1, banner11,Interstitials, smart.

at link https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Can we use banner and banner11 add both in our app(obviously will show one at a time)? If yes then how we can check what type of add currently showing in app. and how to handel these two different. I am new in this so dont know whether we can use only one type of add banner or any number of them by setting in admob account.

One more issue. can we set time for add.. i.e To show add after every 30 sec or 60 sec for 10-15 seconds ?

Please help me in this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can display multiple ads in a single app. I just tried adding 2 banner ads to the app and it worked.

You have to maintain instances of the ads in your controller. As soon as you call the loadRequest function the ads will start loading and will show up.

About your second issue, you have to have to manage it yourself. I mean you have to send the request for ad after some 30 - 60sec delay and then remove the ad after 10-15 secs.

Comment: @KsK Download SDK from here. Within that you will find the sample. http://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googleadmobadssdkios.zip

Comment: this is for google analytics not for google adds.. i already have the sdk

Comment: @KsK Nope.. Got it from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download . You can check it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You sound quite confused, Banners I and Banners II are just two-step tutorials, with Banners II being more in-depth than Banners I.

The best way to show Google Ads is to use one banner and share it between all apps. Here a manager I wrote that you can try:https://github.com/jackwu95/JWGADManager